# How can I make my JavaScript code more DRY?

Tags: javascript, dry, repeat

My code looks pretty untidy, because I'm not really used to coding in JavaScript. In PHP, I would use a for loop and dynamic variables, but I can't get dynamic variables to work in JavaScript.

How would you DRY this up?

```
document.getElementById("colorpicker01").onchange = function()  {myFunction01()};
function myFunction01() {  hexinput01.value = colorpicker01.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker02").onchange = function() {myFunction02()};
function myFunction02() {  hexinput02.value = colorpicker02.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker03").onchange = function() {myFunction03()};
function myFunction03() {  hexinput03.value = colorpicker03.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker04").onchange = function() {myFunction04()};
function myFunction04() {  hexinput04.value = colorpicker04.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker05").onchange = function() {myFunction05()};
function myFunction05() {  hexinput05.value = colorpicker05.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker06").onchange = function() {myFunction06()};
function myFunction06() {  hexinput06.value = colorpicker06.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker07").onchange = function() {myFunction07()};
function myFunction07() {  hexinput07.value = colorpicker07.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker08").onchange = function() {myFunction08()};
function myFunction08() {  hexinput08.value = colorpicker08.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker09").onchange = function() {myFunction09()};
function myFunction09() {  hexinput09.value = colorpicker09.value;}

document.getElementById("colorpicker10").onchange = function() {myFunction10()};
function myFunction10() {  hexinput10.value = colorpicker10.value;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This seems like a question better for [codereview.se].

Comment: Have a look at closures. And use an array for your `hexinput`s, not dynamic variables.

Comment: **_In PHP, I would use a for loop and dynamic variables, but I can't get dynamic variables to work in JavaScript_** -- Why not? What didn't work? What did you try? These are all things that we can help with in SO. Please reformulate your non-question.

Comment: Side note: if you use dynamic variables in PHP, that needs work too. Dynamic variables are a big sign of code smell.

Comment: Something like `document.querySelectorAll(".colorPicker").forEach(function(el) { el.onchange = function() { document.getElementById(this.id.replace("colorPicker","hexinput")).value = this.value;} });`

Comment: @mplungjan Not bad, though it does make assumptions about the way elements should be named in markup.

Comment: @Timir - if not then `document.querySelectorAll("[id^=colorpicker]")...` - I just prefer using a class

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Assuming the `myFunction` series of functions aren't used elsewhere, you'd do:

```
var addChangeListener = function(elem, hexInput) {
    elem.onchange = function() {
        hexInput.value = elem.value;
    }
};

const elements = { 'colorpicker01':'hexinput01', 'colorpicker02':'hexinput02', 'colorpicker03':'hexinput03'}

for(elemName in elements) {
    const elem = document.getElementById(elemName);
    const hexInput = document.getElementById(elements[elemName]);
    addChangeListener(elem, hexInput);
}
```

And if you need to reuse the `myFunction` functions as well, it's easy enough to define them at runtime too.

Comment: This is only a tiny bit less DRY than the original.

Comment: Original? Is there a link to this source quoted elsewhere?

Comment: You cannot call this dry `const elements = { 'colorpicker01':'hexinput01', 'colorpicker02':'hexinput02', 'colorpicker03':'hexinput03'}
` - especially not in front of a loop

Comment: Right, one optimization would be to presume element naming patterns, which I'd like to avoid doing. To each his own I guess.